# Data table - Export table with multiple rows in the header to PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, datatables

Based in the following [table](http://codepen.io/wefs/pen/NRrwkG) I need to export it to a PDF file, the header has two rows in the view but in the PDF has only one. I don't know if I missing something. In order to get the same table in the generated file, any idea?

**HTML table:** I need to show the header (colspan and rowspan) in the PDF file generated.

```
<table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <!-- Two rows in the header but only one in the PDF -->
    <thead> 
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Name</th>
            <th colspan="2">HR Information</th>
            <th colspan="3">Contact</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>5421</td>
            <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>

            .
            .
            .

        <tr>
            <td>Donna Snider</td>
            <td>Customer Support</td>
            <td>$112,000</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>4226</td>
            <td>d.snider@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#example').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    orientation: 'landscape',
                    pageSize: 'LETTER'
                },
                'print'                    
            ],

            "bLengthChange": true,
            "searching" : false,
            "info": false,
            "ordering": false,
            "paging" : true,
        })
    });
```